# Return JSON response inlcuding HTTP status code in a string

Tags: c#, json

How to return JSON response with HTTP status code in a string.

What format to use?

I tried the code below

```
protected override string ConvertResponseToString(HttpWebResponse httpResponse)
    {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            HttpStatusCode statusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)httpResponse).StatusCode;
            **return statusCode + streamReader.ReadToEnd();**
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference the .NET framework assembly System.Web.Helpers.dll in your project.

Then use the JSON class which converts a data object to a string that is in the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format:

```
return Json.Encode(statusCode + streamReader.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: Is this possbile without referencing new DLLs? 

i just want to append HTTP status code in JSON response in a correct format.

Comment: I assume that the http response is already formatted as Json... You can then do (position 0 will be { character) : 

return streamReader.ReadToEnd().Insert(1,"statusCode:"+statusCode+",");